# Laptop Won't boot directly to windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios, boot-manager

Everytime I turned on my computer it leads me to a black screen with the message of "Reboot and select proper device boot". What I am doing in order to successfully lead the booting process to windows 10 is by accessing the Boot Manager and I have to choose "Windows Boot Manager" or "launch efi shell from filesystem device" or by pressing Esc button to load default. Now i don't know how to fix this? I've been searching the internet for several days for an answer.

Note: I just installed a fresh windows 10 on my laptop and my BIOS settings are on default.

Comment: I would suggest going into bios and setting your default boot device to wherever you installed your new windows 10. I would imagine this could be the culprit however depending on how you set everything up results may vary. Usually if everything went correctly with the install, you should only need to tell your bios where to look when it "boots" the OS which would be the installation destination. if this does not do the trick then I would try seeing if you have any "one time boot" or alternative order set up in your boot sequence. Only other possibility I would imagine is flawed install.

Comment: This problem existed since before installing windows 10. I installed windows 10 using UEFI'S command prompt since my laptop cannot boot from my flash drive. The installer I used is also good , I use it before on another computer and works good.

Comment: Can I disable all other options on boot except my hard drive where the OS is installed?

Comment: i'm not sure if you would be able to do that, however in my experience when you go into bios you should see a few different options. From there find out which drive has your windows 10 installed on it, and tell bios to boot from that. I'm not sure how your laptop is set up but it should be relatively simple to figure out unless you have some sort of custom raid or virtual array's setup. If you are only looking for physical drives it should be iether A or B, and I would imagine the hard drive would have the name of the manufacturer or some coding to denote this in the bios menu ex: Toshiba XXX.

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms It's a little bit more complicated than what you think if it's a new UEFI machine. You're thinking BIOS, lagacy...

Comment: ... but it's still true that **the drive containing the EFI partition** should be given priority in the boot order/list (this is *not* necessarily the same drive where the OS or more than one are installed). But then, even with the correct drive in first, users also need to go to a different menu and select the correct boot entry for the OS intended to boot by default.

Comment: If its a machine that has Eufi and bios see if you can set it to boot into bios instead of eufi and then you solved the problem. If Bios is non existent on your machine then you will have to try to do similar which I'm sure is possible but through eufi setup. I work with both bios and eufi all day and I don't seem to have the issues you are having.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways to troubleshoot the issue:

Way1,

1. Set the boot order: select the correct local hard drive to boot.
2. Turn off **Secure Boot**.
3. Restart the computer to see if it can boot successfully.

[image]

Way2,

If the way1 does not work, we try to reinstall operating system by our current USB flash drive.

Way3,

1. Prepare a new USB flash drive with at least 4GB of space (if our current USB flash drive needs to be used on other devices, but if we don't need it and we can format it).
2. Download a new Win 10 1803 ISO image.
3. Burn this ISO into a USB flash drive with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) tool and make this USB flash drive into UEFI boot mode.

For the detail how to install Windows 10 from USB with UEFI support, we can refer the articles: [How to install Windows 10 from USB with UEFI support](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-usb-bootable-media-uefi-support)

[image]